# Pdfsharp Migradoc - Remove footer from first page

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm using pdfsharp+migradoc for creating pdf, creating a section, and having multiple pages in it with the footer.
But I don't want the footer on the first page, how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the `PageSetup` specify that you want different headers and footer on the first page and leave the first-page footer empty.